# coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instancemethod found after upgrading django from 1.2.3 to 1.6.5

Tags: python, unicode, django-1.6

I have a django app with version 1.2.3 and updated to 1.6.5 and the app is working fine, but the admin url is not working and facing with the below error when i accessed `localhost:8000/admin/`

**Traceback**

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/user/.envs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/user/.envs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in wrapper
  215.                 return self.admin_view(view, cacheable)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/.envs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  99.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/.envs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/.envs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in inner
  198.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/.envs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  52.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/user/.envs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py" in index
  358.                             model_dict['admin_url'] = reverse('admin:%s_%s_changelist' % info, current_app=self.name)
File "/Users/user/.envs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse
  503.                 app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
File "/Users/user/.envs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in app_dict
  329.             self._populate()
File "/Users/user/.envs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  290.                     for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
File "/Users/user/.envs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in reverse_dict
  315.             self._populate()
File "/Users/user/.envs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _populate
  278.                     lookup_str = callback.__module__ + "." + callback.__name__

Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/
Exception Value: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instancemethod found
```

And when i shifted the django version to 1.5.3 its working without error, so what wrong with the latest version, does we need to do any changes with unicode settings ?

**Edit:**

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from feeds.sitemap import SITEMAP

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
  # Core Website Pages
  (r'^$', 'core.views.homepage'),
  # Site Map
  (r'^sitemap.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': SITEMAP}),
  # Admin pages
  (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  (r'^search/', include('search.urls')),
)
# Static Content Code, Used Only For Development
import os.path

static = os.path.join( 
  os.path.dirname(__file__), 'media'
)
new_static = os.path.join( 
  os.path.dirname(__file__), 'new_media'
)

if settings.DEBUG:
  urlpatterns += patterns('',
      (r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': static}),
      (r'^new_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': new_static}),
  )
```

**search/urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from search.views import SiteSearch

urlpatterns = patterns('search.views',
    url(r'^$', SiteSearch(), name='site_search'),
)
```

**search/views.py**

```
from haystack.views import SearchView

class SiteSearch(SearchView):

    def get_results(self):
        model_search_form = self.form_class(self.request.GET)
        model_search_form.is_valid()
        models = model_search_form.get_models()
        if self.query:
            search_results = self.form.search()
            if len(models) == 1 and models[0].__name__ == 'Press_Releases':
                search_results = search_results.order_by('-date')
            return search_results

        return []
```

Comment: Specifically, one of your view methods appears to have a `__name__` or `__module__` *method*.

Comment: So my app was vey huge one maintaining from years, so i had many third party apps customized, and i had this `__module__` at many places, so it was causing the error ?

Comment: Your first `patterns()` definition is incomplete; a closing `)` is missing. Serving static files was overhauled in 1.3, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/static-files/

Comment: The view to serve static files is now named [`django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve), perhaps that is the big change here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : Sorry that was just typo when pasting in to SO, and tried by replacing the old view with 'django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve' and still facing the same error

Comment: And `core.views.homepage` is just a function, or is it a class?

Comment: Actually the app as written django 1.2.3 so everything is function based

Comment: I'd do a bisect search here: disable half the urls, try and run. If the error is still there, then disable half of what remained, otherwise swap halves, until you narrowed down exactly what URL configuration is triggering this.

Comment: The documentation for haystack [*used to recommend you use a `__name__` method*](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/commit/5d57e53ffce472c581a9e30f66f4ba3b1b8d43bb); did you perhaps omit that from your post here?

Comment: Actually i just added a __name__ method inside actual SearchView like `def __name__(self): return "SearchView"` which was not there by default, so now by uncommenting this added method the error disappeared, but whats wrong if we add the __name__ method to the SearchView class ? is it collapsing some where  ?

Comment: On every other Python class, `__name__` is a *string*; making it a method breaks a lot of tools, including Django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception is caused by an older Django-Haystack release. Upgrade it, it is incompatible with Django 1.6.

In [version 1.0 at least](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-haystack/blob/1.0.X/haystack/views.py#L29-L30) the `SearchView` class defines `__name__` as a *method*, which goes against the normal use in Python where that attribute is a string instead.

Comment: I have done many customizations to haystack, so if i upgrade i need to recustomize the app again :(

Comment: @shivakrishna: Then upgrade in small steps. 1.1 doesn't appear to have that problem.

Comment: ok sure i think its better to upgrade to newer version anyway, but what exactly the actual use of `__name__` method in python(may be this is a basic python question but want to know it in the words of a python geek like you), removing it will cause any problems ?

Comment: @shivakrishna: See the [datamodel](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html), for classes, `__name__` is the class name. This is used in introspection.